# how to add Terms & Conditions to my app in Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console, privacy-policy

I uploaded a Privacy Policy and I would like to add Terms&Conditions.

Where can I do it in the Play Console? I don't find any button\text field to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to add Terms & Conditions for an app listing page, only a Privacy Policy.

[image]

You can add Terms & Conditions in app screens.

Comment: using this approach, it ain't needed to develop a script using for example "SharedPreferences"  to keep the flag of accepted terms, simple and standard/uniform .